# Double click on a map object in amMaps using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, amcharts, ammap

I am working on an application which is using ammaps. I have a number of points located on the map based on longitude and latitude value. I have achieved single click functionality by using the following code:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
                        $scope.$apply(function(){
                            $scope.colorPoints();
                            $scope.selectedRow = event.mapObject.idBase;
                        });
                });
```

I want to achieve the functionality of double click. Could anyone let me know how I could do that in amMaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, amMap does not support double-click events. However, you can simulate it with a `clickMapObject` event.

For that you'll need to ignore the first click. If the subsequent `clickMapObject` happens within 500ms or so, you register it as double-click.

Something like this:

```
map.addListener( "clickMapObject", function( event ) {
  if ( false !== map.clickedObject && map.clickedObject === event.mapObject ) {
    // doubleckick
    map.clickedObject = false;
    $scope.$apply( function() {
      $scope.colorPoints();
      $scope.selectedRow = event.mapObject.idBase;
    } );
  } else {
    clearTimeout( map.clickedObjectTimeout );
    map.clickedObject = event.mapObject;
    map.clickedObjectTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
      map.clickedObject = false;
    }, 500 );
  }
} );
```